# What Boeing 747 rejected takeoff and runway excursion accident is detailed in this video?

Tags: accidents, rejected-takeoff

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW7znizsUEw) details with an example why not to reject takeoff after $V_1$.

It contains an example of a 747 running off the end of the runway, due to a rejected takeoff past $V_1$ prompted by an engine fire warning. It would appear to be a -200 combi variant with rear cargo door. Faint 'Air France' titles are visible.

What aircraft and flight was this?

Comment: The first part of that video reminds me of some crash I read about where an unnoticed tire damage caused overheat and fire inside the plane.

Comment: @PlasmaHH [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigeria_Airways_Flight_2120)?

Comment: Yep, I think that was the one.

Answer (score 12):

The copilot rejected the takeoff above V1 in response to the engine fire warning.

The aircraft in question:

- Air France plane operating as flight 187
- Boeing 747-200 SCD (side cargo door) registration N4506H
- Aircraft had company number 22794 and manufacturer serial number 558.

The incident occurred on the 24 of July 1988 at Delhi airport. An overview can be found [here](http://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19880724-0).

Comment: Ask a question and then answer it yourself. Is that becoming a trend on SE? ? :p

Comment: @VictorJuliet that's always been possible on SE. Since I had to search for it and look it up I figured why not to share it :)

Comment: @VictorJuliet Perfectly acceptable on SE.

Comment: @VictorJuliet it is not a trend yet but it is fine, acceptable and encouraged.

Comment: @VictorJuliet See [this meta question](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1576/62)

Comment: I couldn't find any reference of it on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_accidents_and_incidents).

Comment: Ok, now I'm curious why this plane had a U.S. registration number, rather than a French one.

Comment: @reirab Aircraft, and especially freighters, are often contracted to carriers other than the actual operators. I flew 747s under call signs for Air India, Garuda Indonesia, Cargolux, UPS, British Airways, and Japan Airlines that I can remember offhand. In three of those instances, the aircraft were repainted in the livery of the contracting carrier. In all of those instances save UPS, we were a U.S. registered aircraft operating for a foreign carrier.

Comment: @Terry Ah, yeah, lease makes sense. It looks like they did later re-register the aircraft with a French registration (F-GCBF.)